# Rank Against Only Like Cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, rank

I need to rank a cell only against the similar cells dynamically. I  have key cells that indicate whether a cell is like or not that looks like A|1,A|2,A|3,B|2,C|4,etc. I only want to rank A|1, against other A|1 Cells, and not B|2 cells, or A|2 cells. Does an answer for this exist elsewhere, and is there any way to do it without using VBA?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems vague. Could you explain more?

Comment: Don't use a code like A|1 to refer to a cell, that's confusingly close to A1. Use a naming scheme which actually relates the type of information being held. Apart from that, what do you mean by 'rank'? Like, with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example

```
 A|1    5   1
 A|1    2   2
 A|2    6   2
 A|2    9   1
```

The formula in C is

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$4=A1)*($B$1:$B$4>B1))+1
```